# Take Screenshot in SwiftUI Preview

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have some nice dummy data built out for my previews and don't want to have to replicate it on the simulator or my personal device (where I use the app myself with my own data)... How can I screenshot the preview window? Ideally would like to use it for App Store templates I've built in Figma.

Thanks [image]

Comment: Do you realise you literally put a screenshot of a preview in your question?

Comment: Unrelated: You mentioned that "It's best to have 5 challenges or less" in the first footer, but you have 6 in your preview. A bit of a contradiction don't you think?

Comment: @Sweeper I want the raw image without the phone and don’t want to have to crop it each time

Comment: @Timmy it’s not a core limitation, just a hit and wanted to test the helper text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the preview device to your physical device and it will show the preview on your phone with the exact data that is in the Preview. Use the dropdown in the bottom left corner to select your phone. Now you can take screenshots on your physical device.

### Xcode 15 and above

[image: preview device dropdown in xcode 15]

### Xcode 14 and below

[image: preview on device button on xcode 14]

Comment: A notice, it's only available on XCode 15 and above.

Comment: @son correct, although XCode 14 and below also have the option to display the preview on a physical device but it's a different button. I've updated the answer

Comment: @Kushagra amazing! Learn something new every day, thank you

Comment: @Kushagra when I preview on my physical device, it blends my personally entered data with the preview container data. Any way around this?